# Resistor and power supply

Tags: power-supply, power, resistors

A 1.5kohm resistor has a power rating of 3.75W. if it is connected to a 24V power supply, will it be damaged? why?

Comment: Can you calculate how much power the resistor will dissipate if you apply 24V across it?

Comment: Yes, its 0.384 Watts

Comment: Does this mean the resistor will not be damaged due to the fact that the power dissipated is less than the power rating of the resistor?

Comment: Sounds like a logical answer...

Comment: Of course it does!

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat, so that means I will be correct if I put my answer that way?

Comment: Yes.  When you determine the ohmic size of a resistor, you must also determine the power dissipated or physical size so the resistor does not burn up.  0.384W < 3.75W, so the resistor can be used.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be homework with no attempt to solve

Comment: Resistor power ratings are maximums, not minimums.  A resistor won't be damaged by running under its design temperature (i.e., under its rated power for a given ambient).  In fact, running a resistor *right at* its rated power *all the time* will give it a short life; it's not uncommon if you're designing for reliability to bump up to a higher power rating when you get close, rather than trying to ride the edge of the specifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you calculated correctly, the 1.5kohm resistor will dissipate 0.384W if there is 24V across it. So, about 10% of its rated power.

> Will it be damaged?

Not at room temperature, however, at higher ambient temperature you should check the power deration curves.

E.g. the [SMW520RJT](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Data+Sheet%7F1773242%7FE%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_DS_1773242_E.pdf%7F8-1879233-0) made be TE connectivity, a 20 ohm, 5W resistor, has the following temperature curve:

[image]

If I would use this resistor at 10% of its rated power, but at 270°C ambient temperature, it will get damaged.
Although 270°C ambient temperature is a bit extreme example, the same applies when dissipating 4.9W in this 5W rated resistor at 40°C ambient temperature: it will still get damaged.

Comment: Can you please provide a link or citation for the graphic you copied into your answer?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Done. Though the specific part isn't interesting, more the fact that power resistors have a power derating which should be taken into account.